# How does the coulomb which was supposed to lose 12 J of energy after passing through the resistor lose only 4 J? Because it has less joules?

Tags: voltage

[image]

Assume the resistance of each resistor is 36 Ω and the voltage of the battery is 12 V.

Before asking my question, I want to talk about certain points.

Lets suppose there is a battery of 12 V. This means that the potential difference between the negative and positive terminal of the battery is 12 V, and that every 1 C of charge gets 12 J of energy when it is in the negative terminal and spends it in travelling from the negative terminal to the positive terminal through the wire, and in the resistance as well.

In a parallel circuit, the voltage across all the resistors is the same as the voltage of the battery, let's suppose 12 V, and the current gets divided at point 2,3,4,5, and 6.

Now, according to maths, the equivalent resistance of the three resistors is 12 Ω. Then the current flowing should be 1 A, since V = I·R and the voltage is 12 V, and the total resistance is 12 Ω. Then the current flowing through each resistor will be 0.3 A.

Now, the battery is going to give 12 J of charge to every coulomb, but the current through the individual resistors is 0.3 C per second, this means that the electrical energy they will have is only 4 J, but the voltage of resistance is 12 V, meaning 1 C of charge will lose 12 J of energy.

**So, my final question is:**
Will the 0.33 C of charge give only 4 J of energy to the resistor when it was supposed to give 12 J of energy (because the voltage across any individual resistor is 12 V)?

The charge itself did not have 12 J of energy (because it was only 0.33 C of charge); if it would have had more energy, then it would have given more energy, right?

If more charge would have passed, then more energy would have been given to the resistor, right? This might sound silly and obvious, but is it true?

I am in 10th grade and 15 years old, so please avoid using concepts not taught to average 10th grade students, thanks.

Comment: Because that coulomb was split into 3. Each third of it "lost" 4 joules. Now add them up.

Answer (score 1):

I feel the confusion here is power vs energy:

12J per second is entirely different from 12J.

12J per second is power
12J is energy

Joule is energy
Joules per second is power.

---

Battery gives each coulomb charge an energy of 12J.

If the current is 1 Coulomb per second, then 12J is used every second.

If the current is 0.33 Coulomb per second, then 4J is used every second.

If the current is 100 Coulomb per second, then 1200J is used every second.

The battery gives 12J per coulomb in every case.

Comment: Yeah,my question is,when the resistance was supposed to take 12 joules of energy from each coulomb of charge,then how will it take 12 joules of charge from 0.33 Coulomb of charge?how is that possible?

Comment: The resistor still consumes 12 joules from each coulomb. But only 0.33 Coulomb was passing through resistor every second. So the resistor takes 3 seconds to consume 12 joules

Comment: Because in 3 seconds, exactly 1 coulomb of charge passes through the resistor.

Comment: Yeah,that was my doubt,thanks

Comment: Since you're in 10th grade... it is a good idea to think of charge as cars on a road. say `1 Coulomb = 1 million cars`. So the battery gives 12J of energy  per 1 million cars.  Each car carries a very tiny energy. These cars give energy to resistor when they go through it.  When 1 million cars pass through the resistor, the resistor would get 12J energy. If 0.5 million cars pass through the resistor, the resistor would get 6J of energy.  [Edited: RM]

Comment: Notice there are two variables here:  Charge and Time.  Battery gives 12J per 1 Coulomb of charge.   This has nothing to do with time or current.

Comment: Yeah,ok,thanks a lot

Comment: If the current is 0.33 A, then 0.33 Coulomb charge is passing through resistor every SECOND.  Thus the resistor consumes 12*0.33 = 4J energy every second.

Comment: If the current is 100A, then 100 Coulomb charge is passing through resistor every SECOND.  Thus the resistor consumes 12*100= 1200J energy every second.

Comment: Those are not my doubts,my only doubt was that,in 1 second,the individual resistor would consume 4 j of energy from O.33 coulomb of charge because the charge itself because the charge had only that much of energy,right?might seem obvious and silly to you

Comment: @AakashGarain correct. 1 Coulomb gives 12J.   so 0.33 Coulomb gives only 12*0.33 =4Joules.

Comment: Yeah, thanks a lot

Comment: @across. Your input is useful and welcome. I note that you have used "crore" meaning 10,000,000. This meaning would be completely unknown to many users on this site (but obviously completely familiar to people from  India and nearby countries) . It would be useful if you can use powers of 10 and  / or more widely recognised terms so that more readers can benefit.